# Dice Poker Scoring System (Function producing NoneType)

Tags: python, nonetype

So in my coding class we are required to make a "Dice Poker" game. We need to implement a scoring system, however, mine keeps returning a "None", therefore causing issues when I want to add the accumulated score to the base score of 100, since NoneTypes and integers can not be added. I'm aware that I need to fix whatever is causing the None, but I'm not sure how. I believe the problem could be in the "scoring" function, but perhaps it is more lurking in the later parts (After the #Choosing Last Roll or #Scoring output comments) of the function "diceGame". I'm very new to coding, and after hours of looking at this thing I'm not really sure what I'm looking at anymore. Thank you so much for your help!

## Text-based dice game

```
from random import randint

def rollFiveDie():

 allDie = []
 for x in range(5):
    allDie.append(randint(1,6))

 return allDie

def outputUpdate(P, F):

  print(P)
  print(F)

def rollSelect():

  rollSelected = input("Which die would you like to re-roll? (Choose 1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 from the list)   ")
  print("  ")
  selectList = rollSelected.split()

  return selectList

def rollPicked(toRollList, diceList):

  for i in toRollList:
      diceList[int(i) - 1] = randint(1,6)

def scoring(dList):

  counts = [0] * 7
  for value in dList:
      counts[value] = counts[value] + 1

  if 5 in counts:
      score = "Five of a Kind", 30
  elif 4 in counts:
      score = "Four of a Kind", 25
  elif (3 in counts) and (2 in counts):
      score = "Full House", 15
  elif 3 in counts:
      score = "Three of a Kind", 10
  elif not (2 in counts) and (counts[1] == 0 or counts[6] == 0):
      score = "Straight", 20
  elif counts.count(2) == 2:
      score = "Two Pair", 5
  else:
      score = "Lose", 0

      return score

def numScore(diList):

  counts = [0] * 7
  for v in diList:
    counts[v] = counts[v] + 1

  if 5 in counts:
      finScore = 30
  elif 4 in counts:
      finScore = 25
  elif (3 in counts) and (2 in counts):
      finScore = 15
  elif 3 in counts:
      finScore = 10
  elif not (2 in counts) and (counts[1] == 0 or counts[6] == 0):
      finScore = 20
  elif counts.count(2) == 2:
      finScore = 5
  else:
      finScore = 0

      return finScore

def printScore(fscore):
  print(fscore)
  print("  ")


 def diceGame():

  contPlaying = True
  while contPlaying:

      playPoints = 30

      if playPoints > 9:
          playPoints -= 10

      else:
          print("No more points to spend. Game Over.")
          contPlaying = False

      playing = input("Would you like to play the Dice Game? (Answer 'y' or 'n'):  ")
      print('  ')

      if playing == 'y':

          #First Roll
          fiveDie = rollFiveDie()

          outputUpdate("Your roll is...", fiveDie)

           #Choosing Second Roll/Second Roll execution
          pickDie = input("Which die would you like to re-roll? (Choose 1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 from the list)   ")
          print("   ")
          pickDie = pickDie.split()

          rollPicked(pickDie, fiveDie)

          outputUpdate("Your next roll is...", fiveDie)

          #Choosing Last Roll
          pickDie = rollSelect()

          rollPicked(pickDie, fiveDie)

          outputUpdate("Your final roll is...", fiveDie)

          #Scoring output
          scoring(fiveDie)

          finalScore = numScore(fiveDie)

          playPoints += finalScore

          print(playPoints)

      else:

          contPlaying = False
def main():

  diceGame()

main()
```

Comment: The return statements in `scoring()` and `numScore()` have the wrong indentation.